# Supercompact and Reinhardt cardinals without choice

Tags: lo.logic, large-cardinals, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

A friend of mine and I ran into the following question while reading about proper forcing, and have been unable to resolve it:

*Definition.* A cardinal $\kappa$ is *supercompact* if for all ordinals $\lambda$, there exists a  transitive inner model $M_\lambda$ of $V$ and an elementary embedding $j_\lambda: V\rightarrow M_\lambda$ such that $crit(j_\lambda):=\min\lbrace\alpha\in ON: j(\alpha)\not=\alpha\rbrace=\kappa$ and $M_\lambda$ is closed under $\lambda$-sequences (that is, $^\lambda M_\lambda\subseteq M_\lambda$).

Now in the definition of supercompactness, the inner models $M_\lambda$ are allowed to vary with $\lambda$. We could define a large cardinal notion, *uniform supercompactness*, by removing this possibility: $\kappa$ is uniform supercompact if there is a single $M$ and $j$ such that $M$ is closed under all sequences of ordinal length and $j: V\rightarrow M$ is an elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$. But in ZFC, this is not an interesting notion. First, assuming choice, $M$ is closed under sequences of ordinal length if and only if $M=V$ (since two models with the same ordinals and sets of ordinals are equal), so $ZFC\models$ "$\kappa$ is uniformly supercompact $\iff$ $\kappa$ is Reinhardt;" second, Kunen showed that Reinhardt cardinals are inconsistent with $ZFC$. (EDIT: as Joel points out, this statement doesn't actually make sense, as Reinhardt-ness is not a first-order property. One needs to pass to some extension of ZFC which can talk about proper classes directly, like Morse-Kelly set theory, which is the setting Kunen used for his proof.)

However, assuming $\neg$Choice, both of these points seem suspect. It is still open whether Reinhardt cardinals are consistent with $ZF$, and it is unclear to me that $ZF$ alone proves that uniformly supercompact cardinals are Reinhardt. So my questions are the following:

Question 1: Does $ZF\models$ every uniformly supercompact cardinal is Reinhardt?

Question 2: What is the consistency strength of $ZF+$ there exists a uniformly supercompact cardinal?

Obviously $ZF$ proves that every Reinhardt cardinal is uniformly supercompact; also obviously, Question 2 is really only interesting in lieu of a positive answer to Question 1. The most basic obstruction to a positive answer to Question 1 is the fact that given an elementary embedding $j: V\rightarrow M$ with $M$ closed under ordinal-length sequences and $crit(j)=\kappa$, the restriction of $j$ to $M$, $j\upharpoonright M: M\rightarrow M$ is not obviously (to me at least) an elementary embedding.

Comment: Like you say in the last paragraph, it is not clear that the restriction of j to M is going to be an elementary embedding into M in general.   Instead you could consider the restriction of j to smaller models, like the class N consisting of all sets constructible from sequences of ordinals.  Then j does restrict to an embedding N -> N but you still have might have the problem that the embedding is not amenable to the model.  This seems like the bigger issue to me.

Comment: This is an interesting question. The contradiction in ZFC comes from the fact that models with the same sets of ordinals are isomorphic. In ZF it is not true. Monro proved that there is a chain of $\omega$ models, where $V_n\subseteq V_{n+1}$ and they both have the same sets-of-sets-..$n$-times of ordinals, but they are not isomorphic (Jech *The Axiom of Choice*, Ch. 5, Problem 17). This, however is "going up" while inner models are "going down" so there might be some difference there.

Comment: Very nice question. One quibble: it isn't really correct to say that ZFC refutes Reinhardt cardinals, since there is no first-order characterization of Reinhardt cardinals; that is, you can't say "$\kappa$ is a Reinhardt cardinal" in a first-order way. Kunen proved his inconsistency in the second-order Kelly-Morse set theory, but it is also possible to formalize the result in Goedel-Bernays set theory GBC. See http://jdh.hamkins.org/generalizationsofkuneninconsistency/ for a further discussion of this point. 

Comment: I believe (from your remark about ordinal lengths) that you intend that the assertion "for all $\lambda$..." in the definition is meant to be interpreted as, "for all ordinals $\lambda$...". The difference matters, as you likely know, because if you have $j:V\to M$ and $j"A\in M$ for all *sets* $A$, then it follows easily that $M=V$ even in ZF, since if $A$ is transitive, then $A$ is the Mostowski collapse of $j"A$.

Comment: @Joel: good points. I've corrected the question. Also, building off of your first comment, is it obvious that uniform supercompactness is first-order expressible? For that matter, how is supercompactness itself first-order expressible?

Comment: Noah, while we can prove that Reinhardt cardinals are not first order expressible (otherwise let $\kappa$ be the least one, and then consider $j(\kappa)$...), it seems that we should similarly expect the same for uniform supercompactness. But it can be formalized in second-order GBC, as an assertion about a class $j$ and a class $M$. One replaces the assertion that $j$ is fully elementary with the assertion that $j$ is $\Sigma_1$-elementary and cofinal, which implies $\Sigma_n$-elementarity by a meta-theoretic induction. 

Comment: Also, you say that it is also possible to formalize Kunen's inconsistency argument in GBC. I'm not familiar with GBC; is it the same as NBG, and if not, is it a conservative extension of ZFC?

Comment: The super compactness of $\kappa$ is expressible in first-order as the assertion:  for every ordinal $\lambda$, there is a $\kappa$-complete normal fine ultrafilter on $P_\kappa\lambda$. 

Comment: (Not to keep spamming comments, but:) Your most recent comment confuses me somewhat. Is GBC a theory in second-order logic, or by "second-order GBC" did you just mean something similar to "second-order arithmetic?"


Comment: Yes, NBG and GBC are the same; just an alternative acronym. N = von Neumann. It is conservative over ZFC, because you can force to add a global choice class and then just take the definable classes.  So every model of ZFC is the first-order part of a model of GBC. This is not true for KM, since KM proves the existence of satisfaction classes for first-order truth, and hence proves Con(ZFC). 

Comment: We are jumping over each other's comments!  Yes, by "second-order GBC", I just meant that GBC was a second-order theory. Sorry to confuse...

Comment: Is there a way to formalize Reinhardt cardinals and uniform supercompactness without using Choice? The above examples of using NBG or KM to formalize these notions both involve the use of Choice. But we need to work with a Choiceless universe in order to answer Questions 1 and 2.

Comment: wmitt, Yes, it does not require any AC or global AC to formulate the Reinhardt cardinal concept in second-order Godel-Bernays set theory (without AC). So you are correct, wmitt, that we should speak of formalizing it in GB rather than in GBC. The Kunen inconsistency, which rules out Reinhardt cardinals, is a theorem of GBC, with choice. 

Comment: Thanks. If we do drop global AC from NBG, doesn't the resulting lack of a bijection between ON and V entail the existence of an inner model M that's (i) closed under sequences of ordinal length, and (ii) not equal to V? If so, we would seem to have a negative answer to Question 1, making the idea of uniform supercompactness interesting. 

Comment: @wmitt, I don't think that works - uniform supercompactness (and, for that matter, Reinhardtness) doesn't just ask for an inner model with some properties, it asks for an elementary embedding. So even given an $M\subsetneq V$ closed under sequences of ordinal length, that doesn't mean that we have an elementary embedding $V\preccurlyeq M$. (I think what I've said is right; somebody who knows more, please correct me if I'm wrong!)

Comment: I agree that the mere existence of an M with certain properties doesn't mean we have an elementary embedding. Question 1, however, doesn't ask for an e.e.; it asks if all uniform supercompact cardinals are Reinhardt (given ZF). I.e., it assumes that uniform supercompacts and their e.e.'s exist (including a suitable M), and asks if this entails an e.e. of V into V. In NBG without global AC, there exists (I claim) a suitable M distinct from V, thus answering Question 1 negatively. I may be wrong, of course; but even if I am, I don't think it's due to not showing that a certain e.e. exists.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Sorry, I missed the "global" in your comment and didn't understand what you were saying. Actually addressing the point you made: The way I'm familiar with it, NBG doesn't actually have global choice as an axiom; instead, it follows from Limitation of Size. So there are two ways I could understand "dropping global choice" from NBG: weakening Limitation of Size so that only normal AC is provable, or weakening Limitation of Size so that not even normal AC is provable. Both are vague, but some things can be said about them. Any suitable way of doing the former (cont'd)

Comment: will yield a theory which still proves ZFC; in this case, there will be no such suitable model. Specifically, I believe that given any (I suppose wellfounded) model $W$ of this (admittedly vague) version of NBG, it will still be the case that any submodel of $W$ with the same ordinals and sets of ordinals has the same sets as $W$ itself.

If, on the other hand, we weaken Limitation of Size so much that even normal choice is not provable, then we can have such an $M$, but we no longer no that no Reinhardts exist; so we still can't answer 1 negatively.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful response, Noah. Elliott Mendelson dispenses with global AC by positing, in place of Limitation of Size, AC for sets plus a form of Replacement. In that case, ZFC only holds for sets, not for proper classes ("pc's") such as V and M (for M an inner transitive model of V). Hence, ZFC doen't rule out the existence of a suitable pc M, i.e. a pc that witnesses a negative answer to Question 1. Also, a negative answer to 1 is compatible with the existence of Reinhardts; it simply says that the class of Reinhardts doesn't include all of the uniform supercompacts. 

Comment: I noticed that the definition you give of supercompact is explicitly second-order. With AC, this is equivalent to the existence of normal fine measures, but without AC, one no longer has the Los theorem and so it isn't clear that your second-order definition has a first-order equivalent.  

Comment: Hm, good point. Is there a "uniformized" version of the existence of normal fine measures that might be to the existence of normal fine measures what the second-order definition of uniform supercompact is to the second-order definition of supercompact? (If that makes any sense.) Looking at it now, I don't see one . . .

Comment: I know that this is quite old by now, and I'm sure that Noah and several others here would have no problem tackling @Joel's last comment. Here is my "starting suggestion" to modify Woodin's definition: $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-supercompact* if there is $\lambda'\geq\lambda$ s.t. for every large enough $\alpha$ there is an elementary $j\colon V_\alpha\to N$, where $N$ is transitive, the critical point is $\kappa$, $j(\kappa)=\lambda'$, $V_\lambda\subseteq N$, and $N^\lambda\subseteq N$. (Some indices might need a small tweak, e.g. $V_{\lambda+1}$ or so to be "faithful to the idea".)

Comment: The point here is that we require $j(\kappa)$ to be the same in all of these embeddings. Clearly if there is a class embedding its restrictions satisfy this property. And now we can quantify over all $\lambda$ if need be.